# Manually increment a column value in SQL Server database through query when date < currentdate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just starting learning database so this would be a rather basic question but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

I have a table in database in which there is a column named Date where I store a date( Just the date in the format dd/mm/yy) and there is another column named IntegerColumn in which initially I am storing the integer value 0.

Question is

**How to increment the integer value 0 by 1 in IntegerColumn when the date in Date is less then the current date.**

Note that the data type for the column storing the date is nvarchar(50) and I am keeping in check the date format i.e dd/mm/yy through code behind in my asp.net application. And additionally I am using SQL Job Scheduling for the query to recur each time SQL Server finds the date less then the current date.

I have done this much...

```
DECLARE @IncrementValue int
SET @IncrementValue = 1
UPDATE tableA SET IntegerColumn = IntegerColumn + @IncrementValue
WHERE Date < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Seems right to me. What is output of the sql you wrote?

Comment: Unfortunately the query does nothing. I wonder why as you said its alright. I mean it does not increment the value in IntegerColumn.

Comment: any ideas why its not incrementing...?

Comment: Date is a keyword, try typing [Date] in your Where statement

Comment: vgSefa infact the name is ReturnDate in the database and not just Date. I have just choosed a random name here but nevertheless its not incrementing the IntegerColumn. any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHY do you store a date value into `nvarchar(50)` field? That's the issue. 
In this case you [should convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your TEXT field to DATETIME type:

```
...
WHERE CONVERT(datetime,[Date],3) < GETDATE();
```

Comment: valex thanks for the reply. I changed the field to date datatype and also tried the option you have provided but still when I execute the query it does not increment the value. any ideas ?

Comment: @user3662855: Is it possible that `IntegerColumn` is not 0 but NULL. Then NULL+1->NULL. Try to change `IntegerColumn + @IncrementValue` to `ISNULL(IntegerColumn,0) + @IncrementValue`

Comment: Thanks alot valex. Infact the IntegerColumn was set to ALLOW NULL. Changed the query as you said, It finally worked.